# Moving from localhost to real URL in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm developing a site with Python and Flask and want to move from localhost in my browser to my team's development server and development site but I'm having problems. I've already looked at the Flask documentation, which recommends using `host='0.0.0.0'` or specifying `SERVER_NAME`. Thusfar, neither of these things have helped. Here's a bit of code to show what I'm doing:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super secret key'
    app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'https://example.org/blah'
    app.run(host=app.config['SERVER_NAME'], port=4343, debug=True)
```

As you can see, instead of `localhost:500`, I want to be able to go into my browser and visit `'https://example.org/blah'` and see the same things.

With this piece of code, I get this error:

```
(py34)user:~/flask$ python app.py
INFO - Connection with server established!
INFO - Server version meets recommendations (v2.9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 18, in <module>
app.run(host=app.config['SERVER_NAME'], port=4343, debug=True)
File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 674, in run_simple
s.bind((hostname, port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

If instead of using `SERVER_NAME` I use `host='0.0.0.0'`, I don't get any errors and it will successfully start `"Running on http://0.0.0.0:4343/"` but I can't follow that url into my browser the same way I can when I connect to my localhost.

What do I need to do to get my flask app running on `https://example.org/blah`?

Also, if it helps to know, I have to `ssh` into my server.

Comment: Note: to avoid changing URLs between production and testing, you can use `/etc/hosts` to shortcut DNS lookups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run with `host='0.0.0.0'` from the server, you should be able to navigate to `example.org:4343` and see your app.

Additionally, `SERVER_NAME` requires the port, per the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/config/#SERVER_NAME):

> the name and port number of the server. Required for subdomain support (e.g.: 'myapp.dev:5000')

Finally, if you want to show you app without a port number, you either need to run it at port 80 (or 443) with root permissions, or using Nginx/Apache to route the request from your domain to the app.

Comment: It appears that with `host=0.0.0.0`, my server automatically posts it at port 443, and I need a symlink in order to view it. In this case, I guess I don't need to specify port 4343, but I don't think Flask will run if I don't give it any port?

Comment: actually i think you should use nginx/apache regardless ... the flask webserver is super hokey, i think it still uses http 1.1

Comment: @maxymoo I'd definitely agree, especially because running Flask without debug mode doesn't serve static files, which would then be the task of Nginx/Apache.